# Programmatically Add image to Crystall report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

how i can show image in crystal report without image path.
I have database CARD with ID (int) and Pic (image).

I add datatable to crystal report dtCard with column  =
id type=string
pic type= byte()

here my code to show the report:

============================================

```
Dim report As New reportCard

Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\docReportCard.rpt"

report.Load(path)

Dim dt As New DataTable("dtCard")

dt.Columns.Add("Id")
dt.Columns.Add("pic")

// dtData return value from database

Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow
row("Id") = dtData.Rows(0).Item("id")
row("pic") = DirectCast(dtData.Rows(0).Item("pic"), Byte())

dt.Rows.Add(row)

report.Database.Tables("dtCard").SetDataSource(dt)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
```

==================================================

When i running the code, nothing error but image cannot show.
Only "System.Byte()" in crystal report.

how i fix this problem?
i want Pic from database show up in my crystal report.

Best regards,
surbakti

Comment: In your schema the data type of the image column should be <xs:element name="logo" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />

Comment: here code from my schema: <xs:element name="image" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />. but still image not show. any idea?

Comment: If you set your schema as the datasource of your report at design time, the data type of your image column should be IBlobFieldObject

Comment: Try loading an actual image from file into the "pic" column using my code. And why would you need to cast the if it's already of Byte() data type.

Comment: where can i set that IBlodFieldObject?

Comment: You don't have to. It is automatically set for you when you assign a datasource to your report at design time if the datatype of the column is xs:base64Binary

Comment: because the error system.byte() so i think i must convert again to byte().

Comment: now System.Byte() not show. but image still nothing. i can see nothing in field that should image will show. what that i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with 1 form and 1 CrystalReport. The form should have 1 Button and 1 CrystalReportViewer Control. Paste this code in the form's code window.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim table As New DataTable("test")
Dim column As DataColumn

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    table = New DataTable("test")
    With table
        column = New DataColumn
        With column
            .ColumnName = "id"
            .DataType = GetType(Integer)
            .AutoIncrement = True
            .AutoIncrementSeed = 0
            .AutoIncrementStep = 1
        End With
        .Columns.Add(column)

        column = New DataColumn
        With column
            .ColumnName = "pic"
            .DataType = GetType(Byte())                
        End With
        .Columns.Add(column)
    End With

    '   create XSD file for report datasource
    '   uncomment this line on first run to create the datasource schema of your crystal report document.
    '   Once schema is created, point your crystal report document's datasource to its location
    '   After setting the data source, when you drag the "pic" column, its datatype will be IBlobFieldObject.
    'table.WriteXmlSchema("E:\TMP\TestReport.XSD")

    '   uncomment the following on succeeding runs, i.e. after setting the data source in the crystal report file
    'ShowReport()
End Sub






Private Sub ShowReport()
    Dim row As DataRow
    row = table.NewRow
    row("pic") = GetImageData(<PATH YO YOUR IMAGE FILE>)
    table.Rows.Add(row)
    table.AcceptChanges()

    Dim crpt As New crpt
    crpt.SetDataSource(table)

    crv.ReportSource = crpt
End Sub






Public Function GetImageData(ByVal cFileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = _
            New System.IO.FileStream(cFileName, _
            System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
    Dim br As System.IO.BinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(fs)
    Return (br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(br.BaseStream.Length)))
End Function
End Class
```

Name your controls like the following:

Button = Button1
CrystalReportViewer = crv

Form = Form1
CrystalReport = crpt

TestReport.XSD contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="test" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="test">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="id" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="pic" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```